# Jsreport.local is not working on IIS server after deployment using asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, jsreport

it is working fine on my local machine inside visual studio, but after publishing my project on IIS real server it throws the following exceptions:

```
Access is denied
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems that your JSReport library didn't have permission to run certain task. Check the IIS permissions to make sure.

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto for replying. My problem is fixed now